# What is a general way to generate all the notes within a key

Tags: python

I'm designing a piece of software in python to aid me in composition and to make useful suggestions while I'm playing.  Currently a key is defined in the following way:

```
noteDict = {"R":"C",  #root
        "m2":"Db",    #minor 2nd
        "M2":"D",     #major 2nd
        "m3":"Eb",    #etc
        "M3":"E",
        "P4":"F",
        "A4":"F#",
        "D5":"Gb",
        "P5":"G",
        "A5":"G#",
        "m6", "Ab",
        "M6", "A",
        "m7", "Bb",
        "M7", "B"}

#stores noteDict, and adds entries for notes in a different format:
#ex: knows that a m6 is the same as a b13 and a D5 is the same as a b5
C = key(noteDict)
```

This works as intended, however it would be nice to be able to have a set of rules that define how a key is constructed as opposed to hand coding it all.  Obvious rules exist such as "Augmented 4th is the Perfect 4th with a sharp", however I'd still need a way to generate the base scale (ie in C major: R M2 M3 P4... - C D E F...) and then apply the modifications to the base scale.

An obvious way to do this is to maintain a table of intervals based on semitones, so if you are told a root (such as C), you could add 3 semitones to the root to reach the minor 3rd (C -> Db -> D -> Eb).

The problem with this method arises when dealing with keys such as Cb major.  Finding the correctly spelled minor third of Cb would add three semitones and spit out D instead of the correct Ebb.  How could I generate a correctly spelled noteDict for an arbitrary key?

Comment: I am afraid your question is too *musical*. Could you maybe describe in less musical terms what it is you are trying to do?

Comment: For example, *"Augmented 4th is the Perfect 4th with a sharp"* is not obvious at all; far from it.

Comment: Since the code cannot know anything without you telling it the proper instructions, I would suggest converting these musical "rules" into code. Python is great for this since you can use`if`, `and`, `in` to define such rules in a few lines... but not many people on SO know the details of these rules to advise properly on how to proceed with this.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a musical logic question, so there's not much I can do to disentangle that! Is there a better place to ask something like this?

Comment: @JacobIRR  I'm looking more for a minimal amount of information that can be used to create a general function that will take the root of a key in, and spit out all of the notes within that key, correctly spelled based on the key signature.  I've currently hard coded all these specific musical rules, but a general function that accomplishes this would be much more maintainable, trustworthy and complete (can generate cases I haven't bothered to write out).

Comment: Think about what constitutes "correctly spelled" in the eyes of a computer. You have to write code that says something like: "If a letter is already listed in a key, use the next letter in line and flatten (or sharpen) it". Trying to write this code and then posting that with an error or question is the best way to get help since the question is currently trapped in the land of rules for sheet music and not programming specifics.

Comment: Is the chromatic approach correct for at least the major intervals—if you pick between, say, D# and Eb based on the starting note?